# How to review a user's outgoing email before approving in Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, powershell, user-accounts, exchange

I want to set up outlook so a users email are reviewed by their manager before emails are sent out internally or externally. Please note that adding mailbox permissions such as Read and Manage is not enough as the user can still send out email's with no option for a manager to review what is sent.

As far as I am aware this can be done for Groups in O365 under message approval. Open to any suggestions. Any PowerShell solutions most appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Really, review a happy birthday? If Outlook/Exchange proper/Exchange API's does not expose this use case, there is little you can do programmatically to address it either. Yet, practically, if you have an org of dozens, hundreds, thousands of users, operationally this makes little sense. The user's manager would be doing nothing else but reading emails, and replies. Slowing business operations to a literal crawl. It would be better to set Exchange policy rule to inspect for mail content, and if that mail violates policy, then block those for review. This is way RMS/AIP/Mail filters are for.

Comment: For your reference about mail flow rules:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/security-and-compliance/mail-flow-rules/common-message-approval-scenarios

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with a `Mail flow Transport Rule`. In short you configure:

```
Apply this rule if...The Sender is
Do the following...Forward to the sender's manager for approval
```

See Example 2 at the following link for more details
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/security-and-compliance/mail-flow-rules/common-message-approval-scenarios#example-2-forward-messages-to-a-senders-manager-for-approval